# Angular - changing the state from the markup

Tags: angularjs

Currently I'm able to change the state from the controller like this:

```
$scope.goTo = function(state){
  $state.go(state);
}
```

---

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-click="goTo('main')">HOME</li>
```

Is there any way to do it straight from the html instead of having to write a controller function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming you're using ui-router you'd use hyperlinks with ui-sref specifying the state to go to. Something like:

```
<li class="list-group-item"><a ui-sref="HOME">HOME</a></li>
```

All of the various routing providers support something similar.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks! Also worth noting that I can add the ui-sref attribute straight to the li tag. no need for an a tag. You rock!

Comment: I didn't know the second part, so thank you. You rock as well!